# Apache Jmeter missing Config Element Http Request

Tags: jmeter

I open a GUI for Apache Jmeter and not all of the features that are shown in videos and tutorials are shown. It's missing the Add > Config Element > Http Request. Where is this config element? Why is it missing from my version of Apache Jmeter?

Comment: what version of java do you have installed? The components are all stored in the same place, %JMETER_HOME%/lib/ext, but some may depend on later versions of java. Make sure the install package has uncompressed properly. Check if any errors show in jmeter.log.

Answer (score 5):

I use linux mint and installed JMeter from the software manager. To get that component, along with other HTTP components, I needed to install the http module along with the main application.

Answer (score 4):

> > Use latest version of JMeter which is 2.11 (at this time of posting this answer).  http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi

You mean 'HTTP Request Defaults'? (It lets you set default values that your HTTP Request)

If yes, as they say, it will be available in the below path.

[image]

If you are looking for 'HTTP Request' - it is NOT a config element. It is a sampler. So you need to have a 'Thread Group' to see a sampler.

So, add a Thread Group first.

[image]

Then Select Thread Group -> Go to Sampler -> HTTP Request.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

When you're on linux and after installing jmeter you miss HTTP Request options you have to run:

```
sudo apt-get install jmeter-http
```

To install missing http module.